# Allocator e placement new

Tags: c++, gerenciamento-de-memória, alocação

Estou com um problema com *placement new* junto com um "allocator caseiro". O problema é que para tipos de dados (int) funciona bem, agora para double, começam a apararecer saídas muito estranhas. As classes:

```
   #include <cstdlib>

template<class T> class my_allocator {
public:
    T* allocate(size_t n);
    void deallocate(T* p, size_t n);
    void construct(T* p, const T& v);
    void destroy(T* p);


};

template<class T>
T* my_allocator<T>::allocate(size_t n)
{
    return (T*) malloc(n);
}

template<class T>
void my_allocator<T>::destroy(T* p)
{
    if( p )
        p->~T();
}

template<class T>
void my_allocator<T>::construct(T* p, const T& v)
{
    char* z = (char*) p;
    char* q = (char*) &v;
    for( int i = 0; i < sizeof(p); ++i )
        z[i] = q[i];
}

template<class T>
void my_allocator<T>::deallocate(T* p, size_t n)
{
    for( int i = 0; i < n; ++i )
        free(p);
}



#include "my_allocator.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template<class T, class A = my_allocator<T> > class vector2 {
    A alloc;
    T* elem;

    int sz;
    int space;

public:
    vector2(): sz(0), space(0) { }
    explicit vector2(int s);

    vector2(const vector2&);
    vector2& operator=(const vector2&);

    ~vector2() { delete[] elem; }

    T& operator[](int n) { return elem[n]; }
    const T& operator[](int n) const { return elem[n]; }

    int size() const { return sz; }
    int capacity() const { return space; }

    void copy(const vector2& arg);

    void resize(int newsize, T val = T());
    void push_back(const T& d);
    void reserve(int newalloc);

};

template<class T>
void* operator new[](size_t n, my_allocator<T>& d)
{
    return d.allocate(n);
}

template<class T, class A>
void vector2<T, A>::reserve(int newalloc)
{
    if( newalloc <= space )
        return;
     T* p = new (alloc) T[newalloc];

    for( int i = 0; i < sz; ++i )
        alloc.construct(&p[i], elem[i]);

    for( int i = 0; i < sz; ++i )
        alloc.destroy(&elem[i]);
    alloc.deallocate(elem, space);
    elem = p;
    space = newalloc;
}

template<class T, class A>
void vector2<T, A>::push_back(const T& val)
{
    if( !space )
        reserve(8);
    else if( sz == space )
        reserve(2*space);
    alloc.construct(&elem[sz], val);
    ++sz;
}
```

Estou usando corretamente o "placement new"?

Answer (score 2):

Em allocate(n), n é o número de elementos, não o tamanho em bytes. O malloc() deveria ser n * sizeof(T). O deallocate() já está correto.

Fonte: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/memory/allocator/allocate/

Answer (score 2):

Para o seu `allocator` ser válido, ele deve se comportar de forma equivalente ao `std::allocator`. Vejo alguns problemas com o seu:

---

#### `T* my_allocator<T>::allocate(size_t n)`

Aqui a documentação do [`std::allocator::allocate`](http://pt.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/allocator/allocate) diz:

> Aloca `n * sizeof(T)` bytes de armazenamento não inicializado

No entanto o seu código aloca apenas `n` bytes. Altere para:

```
template<class T>
T* my_allocator<T>::allocate(size_t n)
{
    return (T*) malloc(n * sizeof(T));
}
```

---

#### `void my_allocator<T>::construct(T* p, const T& v)`

Documentação do [`std::allocator::construct`](http://pt.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/allocator/construct) diz:

> Constrói um objeto do tipo em `T` no armazenamento não inicializado apontado por `p`

O importante aqui é `constrói`. Você está copiando byte por byte, mas nem todos os tipos podem ser trivialmente construidos assim. No entanto todos os tipos podem ser construidos usando seus construtores. Aqui faça o seguinte:

```
template<class T>
void my_allocator<T>::construct(T* p, const T& v)
{
    new (p) T(v);
}
```

Aqui a função desse `new` não é alocar memória. Ele constrói um objeto na memória apontada por `p` usando o construtor que pega `v` de argumento (o construtor de cópia).

Comment: Muito obrigado Guilherme!

Comment: Boa, o construct() original funcionaria com int e double, mas causaria um problemão com qualquer tipo mais elaborado (com membros-ponteiros ou membros-referências).

Answer (score 2):

Além do que já foi falado, o `deallocate`também tem problema, deve ser feito apenas um `free`.
O parâmetro `n` é o número de elementos que foi alocado, mas como você faz a alocação de todos eles em apenas um bloco de memória, a desalocação também deve ser única.

Comment: Nem reparei nessa. Bons olhos!

Comment: Como já tinhas contribuído eu me obriguei a fazer uma leitura fina, e acabei percebendo isso, @GuilhermeBernal.